# MYSQL- Count set of data as 1 (Not Like Distinct)

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this for customer order and feedback some questions.table_name:customer_database

```
                         ----------
       ID NAME PHONE ORDER_NO ORDER_VALUE ANSWER DATE
                    ----------
        1  RAM 873      5        500       Super      1/1/2019
        2  RAJ 876      1         400      super     1/1/2019
        3  RAM 873      5         500      Bad        1/1/2019
        4  RAM 873       2         100      Good      30/12/2018
```

I want the result as counting the same set of unique date row as 1 like

```
                       ----------
        ID NAME PHONE Total_visit total_order                         
                          ----------
         1  RAM 873      2           600     
         2  RAJ 876      1           100
```

i want to count as 1 for a set of answer like 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple group by query

```
select NAME, Phone count(*) total_visit, sum(order_value) total_order
from your_Table
group by NAME, Phone
```

Comment: have you seen any similar id there? if we group by similar column there was result return as wrong not i expect. @Simonare

Comment: I accidentally shifted columns :) I believe that you can fix it :)

Comment: anyway thanx for your command keep your service to all. @Simmonare

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found the answer to my own by an inner query

```
SELECT NAME,PHONE,count(PHONE) as total_visit,SUM(ORDER_VALUE) as total_order_value  
from (SELECT NAME,PHONE,ORDER_VALUE FROM customer_database GROUP BY PHONE,DATE) as qry 
GROUP BY PHONE
```

Comment: not me but possibly because of the questionable group by in the sub query and main query and having a sub query at all.